# This IS the first or This WAS the first

Tags: tense

(1a) This movie **is** the first one ever made.

(1b) This movie **was** the first one ever made.

(2a) This game **is** the first one I ever got for my collection.

(2b) This game **was** the first one I ever got for my collection.

Some of my friends think "is" is correct when you are watching that movie at the time of your talking. This tense is also correct you are holding the game you are talking about.

Which tense of "to be" is correct? Thank you.